# Server 2012 - Control Panel and Server Manager issues

Tags: windows-server-2012

Recently we had an issue with one of our AD domain controllers (Server 2012) which was found to be stemmed from a bad GPO update and resolved with GPUpdate on the system. What's awkward is that the Server Manager window comes up in dashboard mode but all status's are marked as 'unknown'. Everything seems to be working, but we can't get it to properly reflect those settings.

Secondly, we can't open Control Panel > Network and Sharing center. Control Panel loads fine, but clicking on the Network button leads to it freezing and doing nothing.

nets seems to work just fine to make any modifications if absolutely necessary.

It seems like something is stuck? Usually when I see this on a Linux/OS X system it's a DNS issue, but nothing so far seems to indicate that as the problem on this host.